# WIndows Memory raising

Tags: java

Hello i have one aplication that use java.swing.timer and this is in loop. The problem is that my windows memory process still glow up, and dont stop. I tried to clean my variables, use System.gc() etc... and dont work. I maked a sample to test this with thread, timerstack and swing timer, im  adding itens inside a jcombobox and the memory is still raising.

Here comes the code:

//My Timers

```
@Action
public void botao_click1() {
    jLabel1.setText("START");
    timer1 = new java.util.Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adicionarItens();
            limpar();
        }
    }, 100, 100);
}

@Action
public void botao_click2() {
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                adicionarItens();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    limpar();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MemoriaTesteView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

private void limpar() { // CleanUp array and jcombobox

    texto = null;

    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
    jComboBox1.setVisible(false);
    //jComboBox1 = null;

    System.gc();

}

private void adicionarItens() { //AddItens

    texto = new String[6];

    texto[0] = "HA";
    texto[1] = "HA";
    texto[2] = "HA";
    texto[3] = "HA";
    texto[4] = "HA";
    texto[5] = "HA";

    //jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

    jComboBox1.setVisible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
        jComboBox1.addItem(texto[i].toString());
    }

    System.out.println("System Memory: "
            + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() + " bytes free!");

}
```

well help please !!! =(

Comment: while in theory a good question, the lack of english in the method names makes it impossible to figure out easily what the intention of this code is

Comment: `System.gc()` doesn't actually do anything, it is just a suggestion to maybe do something, that is if the JVM wants to, which it probably doesn't want to. Therefore useless.

Comment: Yep, `System.gc()` is completely no-oped in many implementations because it was so commonly abused.

Answer (score 2):

### It isn't clear that you actually have a problem from the small snippet of code you posted.

#### Either way, you can't control what you want to control

`-Xmx` only controls the Java Heap, it doesn't control consumption of *native memory* by the JVM, which is consumed completely differently based on implementation.

From the following article [Thanks for the Memory ( Understanding How the JVM uses Native Memory on Windows and Linux )](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/)

Maintaining the heap and garbage collector use native memory you can't control.

> More native memory is required to maintain the state of the
>   memory-management system maintaining the Java heap. Data structures
>   must be allocated to track free storage and record progress when
>   collecting garbage. The exact size and nature of these data structures
>   varies with implementation, but many are proportional to the size of
>   the heap.

and the JIT compiler uses native memory just like `javac` would

> Bytecode compilation uses native memory (in the same way that a static
>   compiler such as gcc requires memory to run), but both the input (the
>   bytecode) and the output (the executable code) from the JIT must also
>   be stored in native memory. Java applications that contain many
>   JIT-compiled methods use more native memory than smaller applications.

and then you have the classloader(s) which use native memory

> Java applications are composed of classes that define object structure
>   and method logic. They also use classes from the Java runtime class
>   libraries (such as java.lang.String) and may use third-party
>   libraries. These classes need to be stored in memory for as long as
>   they are being used. How classes are stored varies by implementation.

I won't even start quoting the section on Threads, I think you get the idea that
`-Xmx` doesn't control what you think it controls, it controls the JVM heap, not everything
goes in the JVM heap, and the heap takes up way more native memory that what you specify for 
management and book keeping.

### I don't see any mention of `OutOfMemoryExceptions` anywhere.

**What you are concerned about you can't control, not directly anyway**

What you should focus on is what in in your control, which is making sure you don't hold on to references longer than you need to, and that you are not duplicating things unnecessarily. The garbage collection routines in Java are highly optimized, and if you learn how their algorithms work, you can make sure your program behaves in the optimal way for those algorithms to work.

**Java Heap Memory isn't like manually managed memory in other languages, those rules don't apply**

What are considered *memory leaks* in other languages aren't the same thing/root cause as in Java with its garbage collection system.

Most likely in Java memory isn't consumed by one single uber-object that is leaking ( dangling reference in other environments ).

Intermediate objects may be held around longer than expected by the garbage collector because of the scope they are in and lots of other things that can vary at run time.

**EXAMPLE:** the garbage collector may decide that there are candidates, but because it considers that there is plenty of memory still to be had that it might be too expensive time wise to flush them out at that point in time, and it will wait until memory pressure gets higher.

The garbage collector is really good now, but it isn't magic, if you are doing degenerate things, it will cause it to not work optimally. There is lots of documentation on the internet about the garbage collector settings for all the versions of the JVMs.

These un-referenced objects may just have not reached the time that the garbage collector thinks it needs them to for them to be expunged from memory, or there could be references to them held by some other object ( `List` ) for example that you don't realize still points to that object. This is what is most commonly referred to as a *leak* in Java, which is a reference leak more specifically.

**EXAMPLE:** If you know you need to build a 4K `String` using a `StringBuilder` create it with `new StringBuilder(4096);` not the default, which is like 32 and will immediately start creating garbage that can represent many times what you think the object should be size wise.

You can discover how many of what types of objects are instantiated with VisualVM, this will tell you what you need to know. There isn't going to be one big flashing light that points at a single instance of a single class that says, "This is the big memory consumer!", that is unless there is only one instance of some `char[]` that you are reading some massive file into, and this is not possible either, because lots of other classes use `char[]` internally; and then you pretty much knew that already.

**I don't see any mention of `OutOfMemoryError`**

You probably don't have a problem in your code, the garbage collection system just might not be getting put under enough pressure to kick in and deallocate objects that you *think* it should be cleaning up. What **you think** is a problem probably isn't, not unless your program is crashing with `OutOfMemoryError`. This isn't C, C++, Objective-C, or any other manual memory management language / runtime. You don't get to decide what is in memory or not at the detail level you are expecting you should be able to.

Answer (score -1):

Java, in theory, is immune to "leaks" of the sort that C-based languages can have.  But it's still quite easy to design a data structure that grows in a more or less unbounded fashion, whether or not you intended that.

And, of course, if you schedule timer-based tasks and the like, they will exist until the time has expired and the task has completed (or cancelled), even if you don't retain a reference to them.

Also, some Java environments (Android is notorious for this) allocate images and the like in a way that is not subject to ordinary GC action and can cause heap to grow in an unbounded fashion.

Comment: I can see. Im a C# programer im not familiar with java, and this come to me. What is the best practice to do a loop in java? Can i dispose the array and jcombobox? I tested without jcombobox and the memory dont raised too much? Is that right?

Comment: In general, you don't manage memory.  "Good practice" is to null "references" (pointers) to large objects that you will no longer be using, to make them more readily available to GC, but this is only really necessary for references that are stored in some other long-lived object.  And GUIs have their own obscure rules.  (And, outside of Android, there's no need to use System.gc().  In fact, many Java implementations no-op it because it's so often abused.)